# Чтение данных из двух разных типов значений

Tags: python, pandas

Сложно объяснить словами, что я хочу поэтому сразу с кода, так понятнее:

1. Получаем данные через `API`  с сервера в таком виде:

> ```
> {
>   'name': 'testblavla'
>   'result': [
>     { 
>       'value1': 'value1', 
>       'value2': 'value2',
>     },
>
>     { 
>       'value1': 'value1', 
>       'value2': 'value2',
>     }
>     ],
>   'time': 'time'
> }
> ```

Необходимо прочитать все данные из массива `result` - читаем:

```
self.df = pandas.DataFrame(res['result'], columns=['value1', 'value2'])
```

Теперь суть, как захватить еще и `time` из запроса и чтобы все это прочитать за раз, а не читать сначала `result`, затем `time`, а затем "канкатенировать" столбцы.

Пробую так:

```
self.df = pandas.DataFrame(res['result'] & res['time'], columns=['value', 'time'])
```

`pandas` вообще так умеет?

Comment: зачем что-то конкатенировать? `df["time"] = res["time"]`. а так пандас много чего умеет, но вряд ли, как и я, понимает, что вы хотели сказать в `res['result'] & res['time']`

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо за ответ, рассматривал такой вариант, но это получается 2 операции, а у меня там с API прилетает около ляма строк(((, хочется сэкономить время)

Comment: Не думаю, что именно это будет сильно тормозить